# Databinding in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, database, visual-studio, data-binding

sorry for any inconveniece caused.

Would like to ask about database or rather databinding

My Window look like this: http://i25.tinypic.com/a0x5kn.jpg

The browse button is look up the "My Network Place"

```
private void browseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
 Type t = dialog.GetType();
 System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("rootFolder", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
 fi.SetValue(dialog, 0x0012); dialog.ShowDialog();
 dialog.ShowDialog();
 string selected = dialog.SelectedPath;
 computerText.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
 }
```

So now my computerText.Text pass info, for eg: Computer1

Now for the login, I want a database to see whether the info of the computerText is under which username and password. I have already created a database using Microsoft Access which look like this...

```
id computerName loginID password
1  Computer1      com1    123456
2  Computer2      com2    234567
```

So i roughly type the command for the loginBtn...

```
private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 // if the computerText.Text == my datasource's data [computerName] && loginName.Text == my datasource's data [loginID] && password.Text == my datasource's data [password]
 {
  loginStatus.Text = "Login Success!";
 }
 else
 {
  loginStatus.Text = "Login Failed!";
 }
```

So my question is:

1) How to bind my database that I have now?

2) how to code the above codes that I wanted to do?

Help needed =[

***Updated***
Have done the following code:

```
private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
OleDbConnection conn;
OleDbCommand comm;
OleDbDataReader dr;
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Database1.accdb");
comm = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Remote where loginId =@id and password=@pass", conn); 
comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "loginID")); 
comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "password"));
conn.Open();
dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
loginStatus.Text = "Login Successfully";
}
else
{
loginStatus.Text = "Login Failed!";
string message = "Wrong username/password is been entered!";
string caption = "Alert!";
MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.OK;
MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);
}
}
```

Prompt error: "The type or namespace name 'oleDbType' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

And if i Remove the System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, it works perfectly fine, but when I type according to my database in my username and password, it prompt me Login Failed.. EG:

```
Computer Name : Computer1
Username: com1
Password: 123456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fMay be something like this, create a connection and than read from your access file.

```
 OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbCommand comm;
    OleDbDataReader dr;
    conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\db1.mdb");
    comm = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Table1 where loginId =@id and password=@pass",conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "loginID"));
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "password")); 

    conn.Open();
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close();
if(dr.hasrows)
{
//login success
}
else
 //login fail
```

Than you can authenticate by using **dr** against the user input.  Put this above your commented line.

Comment: Hello... how to authenticate by using dr against the user input? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to change the select query accordingly based on your user table and append a where clause to check (authenticate) the loginID and Password. Then use dr.HasRows to see whether the user exist or not.

Comment: sorry to say that, I dun really understand =\ any step by step method so i can follow? thanks agn, and sorry...

Comment: ok, see the code above, I have updated, actually, its doing the following steps -
-connect to access using oledb connection string.
-use the select statement with where clause to query the login user's -information is exist or not.
-Execute the statement 
-Check the select statement is returning any result.  

If returing result set got rows means the authentication is success other wise its fail because the user information entered was not match.

Comment: Hello, this code couldn't work on my visual studio...

comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "loginID")); 
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass",System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, "password"));

oleDbType was underline red. Its error is: "The type or namespace name 'oleDbType' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: but when I remove the System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20, it works perfectly fine.... But when I type the correct info in that time it prompt me Login Failed...

Comment: its depends on the data type in side your access, so refer to your access file.  You need to place a  break point and debug as well.  You also need to refer to the system.data.oledb.

Comment: I already define the system.data.oledb already, using System.Data.OleDb; still have the red line at System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20... and sorry to ask what you mean by place a break point and debug?

Comment: just change from System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20 to OleDbType.VarChar ,20 in both line and you need to refer to your acess file for the correct datatype "System.Data.oleDbType.NVarChar,20," is just an example.

Comment: Now i have one more error... which is on dr = comm.ExecuteReader(); it says: Parameter @id has no default value.

Comment: I think you need to replace with this -
 new OleDbParameter("@id",txtUserId.Text) //txtUserId is your text box.

Comment: Yep also for the next @pass parameter :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! I manage to solve my problem! THANKS!